# После выполнения GET запроса нужно очистить его из браузерной строки

Tags: php, get

Вот как я решил эту задачу:

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  header("Refresh: 1; url = /");
}
```

Работает но по логике это не верное решение. Так как если скрипт не успеет выполниться за 1 секунду то будет что-попало. Есть у кого какие предложения по решению этой задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« – Элементарно, Ватсон!» — часть, что обрабатывает GET параметры, не должна ничего выводить. А по завершении обработки, просто отредиректить пользователя на «чистый» URL:

```
$data = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'data');
if( $data){
    // что-то сделали с данными, записали в БД
    header('Location: http://www.primer.ru/');
    exit();
}
// выводим страницу для тех, что без параметров пришёл
```

Общие правила хорошего тона предписывают передавать параметры, которые что-то меняют в данных, исключительно POST запросом.

Comment: а как сделать что бы по клику по ссылку отправлялся POST запрос??? :)
Решил использовать буфферизацию вывода дабы можно было использовать отправку заголовка в конце скрипта уже после выводов. Вот что хотел, а практика буфферизации вывода нормальна или лучше не использовать её?

Comment: Отправить заголовки после контента вы не сможете в принципе. Да и зачем это? Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно принять данные, сформировать страницу и вывести её, но так, чтобы URL был без query string, так? Вот и отправляйте данные постом:

    <form method="post" action="./">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1">
    </form>

    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()">ссылка</a>

И

    <?php
        // 1) приняли пост
        // 2) обработали данные, сделали что нужно
        // 3) вывели страницу
    ?>

Comment: а если js у пользователя отключен? Нет это не вариант... Лучшее решение это буфферизация вывода как по мне!

Comment: Какая такая "буфферизация", это о чём вообще?

Comment: Буферизация нипричём. Просто поместите всю логику в начало. Четкие правила: Пришли данные? — Ничего не выводим, только редиректим. Нет данных? — Показываем страницу.

Comment: у и так можно. @klopp буферизация вывода если она включена позволяет отправлять заголовки в любом месте скрипта. _http://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.outcontrol.php

Comment: Это я знаю. Я не понимаю, при чём тут она вообще. Зачем делать какие-то действия и накапливать результат, если в конечном итоге всё это окажется ненужным?

Comment: Зачем делать какие-то действия и накапливать результат, если в конечном итоге всё это окажется ненужным?
Не понял.

Comment: Вам уже несколько раз описали правильную последовательность действий, при которой никакие танцы с бубном и буферизацией не нужны вообще. Или вы неправильно описываете задачу, или что-то здесь не так...

Answer (score 1):

Задача не понятна вообще. Так, что ли?

```
if( isset($_GET['del']) )
{
  // обрабатываем ситуацию
  header( 'Location: /' ); 
  exit();    
}
```

Comment: `Location` [ожидает](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) абсолютный URL.

Comment: Согласен, по RFC положено :) Но клиентам уже давно пофиг, не понимающих относительный просто нет...